# Searching for keywords from a table, in a generic text

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, keyword, keyword-search, tsvector

I have created a table that contains a list of keywords and a code that identifies synonyms. I.e. All keywords with the same code are to be considered the same keyword.

`varchar varchar                     tsvector
C1000   AI                          'ai':1
C1000   Artificial intelligence     'artifici':1 'intellig':2
C1001   Algorithms                  'algorithm':1
C1002   Software Design             'design':2 'softwar':1
C1003   ui design                   'design':2 'ui':1
C1003   User interface design       'design':3 'interfac':2 'user':1
C1003   user interface engineering  'engin':3 'interfac':2 'user':1`

I would like to build a query that returns the list of keywords found in a given text.

For example, the following text (is just a sample) should return the array: [C1001,C1003].

`A good ui design starts from a good algorithm design, for this you need a good user interface engineering.`

Is there a way to do it with a postgres query or a custom function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Naive Bayes classifier algorithm. It is the most powerful algorithm for text classification. Learn more from [here](https://medium.com/@equipintelligence/bayes-text-classification-machine-learning-algorithms-915d320abcdb)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the text to vector, the keyword to query then check if the vector matches the query

```
=> \d codes 
Column  |       Type        | Modifiers 
---------+-------------------+-----------
code    | character varying | 
keyword | character varying | 

=> select * from codes ;
 code  |          keyword           
-------+----------------------------
C1000 | AI
C1000 | Artificial intelligence
C1001 | Algorithms
C1002 | Software Design
C1003 | ui design
C1003 | User interface design
C1003 | user interface engineering
(7 rows)

=> select distinct code from codes where to_tsvector('A good ui design starts from a good algorithm design, for this you need a good user interface engineering.') @@ plainto_tsquery(keyword);
code  
-------
C1001
C1003
(2 rows)

=> select array_agg(distinct code) from codes where to_tsvector('A good ui design starts from a good algorithm design, for this you need a good user interface engineering.') @@ plainto_tsquery(keyword);
array_agg   
---------------
{C1001,C1003}
(1 row)
```